# C#, Linq, Dynamic Query: Code to filter a Dynamic query outside of the Repository

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, dynamicquery

If you do something like this in your Repository:

```
IQueryable<CarClass> GetCars(string condition, params object[] values) {
    return db.Cars.Where(condition, values);
}
```

And you set the condition and values outside of the repository:

```
string condition = "CarMake == @Make";
object[] values = new string[] { Make = "Ford" };

var result = myRepo.GetCars( condition, values);
```

How would you be able to sort the result outside of the repository with Dynamic Query?

```
return View( "myView", result.OrderBy("Price"));
```

Somehow I am losing the DynamicQuery nature when the data exits from the repository.  And yes, I haven't worked out how to return the CarClass type where you would normally do a Select new Carclass { fieldName = m.fieldName, ... }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dynamic query requires:

- the source be `IQueryable<T>` (so if it is `IEnumerable<T>` or similar, just call `.AsQueryable()` on it)
- an extra dll to be referenced in the code that wants to perform dynamic query
- the appropriate `using` directives to be in place at the top of the local source file

Check those three, and you should be able to add `.Where(condition)`, `.OrderBy(name)`, etc

Comment: Bingo.  That's what late night programming buys me.